AD8232/AD8233 not working for sEMG
I am working on an sEMG circuit using the AD8232 and cannot figure out what is going wrong, the circuit isn't outputting the correct signal when connected to the forearm. I am using the 3 lead configuration with RLD on. When I connect IN- and IN+ to each other, the signal is as expected - mid range and flat. But, the circuit is completely unresponsive to EMG when connected to the body with gel electrodes. The output looks similar whether connected to battery or mains voltage source. I had the circuit manufactured with JLCPCB and trust the soldering and construction. Any help greatly appreciated!
SCHEMATIC

REFERENCE TOPOLOGY

LAYOUT

OUTPUT

IA OUT

HP DRIVE

SW PIN

RLD

